# Mysqli Fetch Array Not Returning Result or Error

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am currenlty working on a shopping cart. I have run into an issue where fetch_array is not pulling results from items in a mysql DB. I need this to pull a current quantity and the user notes on the item. It then adds the new value to the old value and combines the notes. Currently, only $newQty & $newNotes are returning a value which is from a form on the page before. Any ideas?

```
$item_query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `rel` WHERE `cart_id` = ' " .$cartId. "' && `id_item` = ' " .$item_id. " '";
$item_result = $mysqli->query($item_query) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);

if($item_result->num_rows == 1) {

    while($getOldItems = $item_result->fetch_array()){
    $oldQty = $getOldItems['amount'];
    $oldNotes = $getOldItems['notes'];

    $newQty = ($oldQty + $item_quantity);
    $newNotes = $oldNotes . $item_notes;

    print("Old QTY: $oldQty, Old Notes: $oldNotes, New QTY: $newQty, New Notes:         $newNotes");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$item_query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `rel` WHERE `cart_id` = '" .$cartId. "' && `id_item` = '" .$item_id. "'";
$item_result = $mysqli->query($item_query) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);

if($item_result->num_rows == 1) {

    $item_query = "SELECT * FROM `rel` WHERE `cart_id` = '" .$cartId. "' && `id_item` = '" .$item_id. "'";
    $item_result2 = $mysqli->query($item_query) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);

    while($getOldItems = $item_result2->fetch_array()){
        $oldQty = $getOldItems['amount'];
        $oldNotes = $getOldItems['notes'];

        $newQty = ($oldQty + $item_quantity);
        $newNotes = $oldNotes . $item_notes;


        print("Old QTY: $oldQty, Old Notes: $oldNotes, New QTY: $newQty, New Notes: $newNotes");
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll try but it's is counting the num_rows correctly. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, I see, you need another query

Comment: Many thanks! I tried before but I must have spelled something wrong.